# Bounding (concave) polygon for multiple rectangles?

Tags: math, geometry, bounding-box

Given a set of intersecting rectangles, is there a standard algorithm to find their bounding polygon?  (A polygon bounding exactly the same region as the union of the rectangles.)  The rectangles can be assumed to all be oriented in the same way, with sides along two orthogonal axes.

In searching I have found algorithms for convex bounding polygons, but here I really would prefer to encompass *only* the area the rectangles cover, which will most likely be concave.

(If the rectangles completely surround a region, its ok for that to be included inside the bounding polygon.)

Comment: **Intersection** of the rectangles? Or **union** of of the rectangles? Bounding polygon would be the union. Yet, for some reason you talk about intersection. BTW, are your rectangles isothetic?

Comment: @AndreyT Yup, I meant union -- just a dumb brain fart.  And the rectangles (and thus the union) will all be isothetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to compute the union of your rectangles, that this is what is commonly known as "merge" operation in computational geometry. It is typically and easily implemented by a sweep-line algorithm.

Sweep-line approach generally requires a sizable initial investment: implementation of sweep-line engine. Once it is done, the engine can immediately be used to easily implement any set-oriented operation on input geometry, like "merge", "and", "or", "diff" and so on.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons

Meanwhile, implementing sweep-line engine for axis-oriented (isothetic) geometry is a rather trivial task. This would be the best approach in situations when you need to process massive inputs, i.e. when the number of rectangles is relatively high. Various edge-traversal based approaches mentioned in other answers will only work well on relatively small inputs.

Comment: This was the most useful answer in actually solving the problem.   While I didn't find any existing algorithm to do what I wanted, it was relatively straight-forward to adapt a sweep-line approach by looking at [several different variations](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lineSweep).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a standard way to do it, but it occurs to me that the vertices of the bounding polygon will be the corners of the rectangles and the points where their sides intersect, and excluding those which lie within a rectangle.

To order the points, start with one point in the set.  It's either the intersection of two edges, or it's a corner, so either way it's guaranteed to be on at least two edges.  Just move along one of the edges until you get to the next point.  Because we removed the internal points already, we'll always hit another vertex point before we end up on the inside.

If a corner of one rectangle is along the edge of another, you have to be careful, because one path away from the corner will lead into the interior of the rectangle.  So there is some element of choosing the right edge to trace along.  But if you maintain the list of points that you excluded because they were in the interior, you know that going to an excluded point is the wrong direction.

**Edit**
Let me try to put it more explicitly.

(1) Start with every side of every rectangle.  Calculate where they intersect and split the edges there.

(2) Now you have a list of segments.  Check the endpoints of every segment to see if they're inside any of the rectangles.

(3) Now take any one of the external endpoints, which is the endpoint of at least one segment which has *another* external endpoint.  Draw the line from your endpoint to the other external endpoint.

(4) That external endpoint should also be an endpoint of a *different* segment that has another external endpoint.  Draw a line to that external endpoint.

(5) Repeat until you get back to the endpoint you started with.

Comment: I've already though about this, but there are unfortunately cases where this doesn't work.  (Different configurations of rectangles result in the same set of points.)  This might be rare enough that it works out OK for my particular use case, but ideally I'd like a "perfect" solution.  :)

Comment: Sure, imagine a 4 by 4 grid of points.  You could connect the dots to form an H, or an I.  Each could be produced by the intersection of three rectangles.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I'm including the points along the "long sides" which could be removed by the algorithm.  It's still not obvious to me how to order the points.

Comment: Well, you want to order them so that the lines between them aren't intersecting each other.  I think you could take a ray from somewhere in the middle and then rotate it and order the points in the order it sweeps over them.  This is what I was getting at with polar coordinates.  But how to pick the origin is a bit more tricky than I made it out to be.  Maybe better to start at any point in the set move along a side of a rectangle which includes that point until you get to another point in the set, etc.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a better means of ordering the points.

Comment: Well, it's exactly the ordering that I'm having problems with.  (I think in general there are all sorts of degenerate cases.)  Perhaps keeping track of the original direction of the path associated with each point will work.

Comment: I edited again, trying to break the procedure up into steps.  I think you should be able to determine which way to go from your starting point by keeping track of which segments it was on, and whether their other endpoint was also external.  The key is not to follow a segment that leads into the interior.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out a pretty simple way to trace out the points.  Start at (say) the leftmost top corner, and head right til you hit a point.  At each new point, turn 90 clockwise if its an original point, otherwise turn ccw.  In this way you'll hit all the external points.  In the majority of cases there'll only be one eligible point in a given direction, but if there's multiple you can just take the closest.  Thanks for the help sorting this out!

Comment: Can you clarify about the "turn 90 degrees" part?  What if the rectangles are at an angle to each other?  Or are you only considering rectangles whose sides are parallel to some fixed axes?

Comment: Ah, damnit, I somehow forgot to mention that in the original problem statement, but yes, that's an ok assumption in my case.  Unless you have a brilliant way to simplify things given this, I'll leave the question as is in case someone needs your solution.  :)